# Uncheck dynamical checkbox -> remove marker

Tags: google-maps, checkbox, google-maps-markers

I really searched everywhere but I can't find my mistake in my code. I have information that is dynamical loaded into a checkbox (I only have one checkbox on my html) because I do not know at advanced how many checkboxes I will need...

This is my code to check if my checkbox is checked, and what is in it. The value is lat,lng and title

```
  $(".chkbx").on("change", function() {
   var selected = new Array();
   //marker.setVisible(false);
   //map.removeOverlay(marker);
  //marker.setMap(null);    


   $("input:checkbox[name=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
   selected.push($(this).val());

   });


  console.log(selected);



for(var i=0; i< selected.length ;i++)
{
    var current = selected[i].split(';');
    var blueIcon = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&' + 'chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';
    var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(current[0], current[1]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({   
        position: siteLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: blueIcon,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

        title: current[2],
        //zIndex: sites[3],
        html: current[2]
    });
    marker.setMap(map);



}

  }

});
```

My markers show on my google map but it is impossible to remove them ... can someone please help me or suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

So for each selected checkbox you create a marker.  What you need to do is add those markers into an array that you can then reference later.

```
// global variable
var markers = [];

$(".chkbx").on("change", function() {
    var selected = [];

    // loop through all the markers, removing them from the map:
    for (var marker in markers) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // then you probably want to clear out the array, so you can then re-insert markers to it
    markers = [];

    $("input:checkbox[name=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).val());
    });

    for(var i=0; i< selected.length ;i++)
    {
        var current = selected[i].split(';');
        var blueIcon = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&' + 'chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(current[0], current[1]);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({   
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: blueIcon,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: current[2],
            html: current[2]
        });

        // you don't need this setMap here, you already specified map in your mapOptions:
        // marker.setMap(map);

        markers.push(marker);
    }
});
```